# Natural number range issue

Tags: php, regex

I need to check if the variable informed has only numbers between **1 and 10** to proceed with the code.
I've tried with many ways, using php native functions *is_numeric, is_int, ctype_digit*, regex and comparing to check if the variable value is in the range, but I ever have an issue.
My first attempt was with this:

```
if($quantity <= 0 || $quantity > 10)
{
    redirect('page.php?msg=error');
    exit();
}
else
{
    //Ok, the value is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 or 10
}
```

But this code let's pass if the variable is, for example: `,1` or `00001`. PHP is_number allow decimals, is_int allow negatives, ctype_digit allows 000001 for example. I tried all, and I think I will can achieve this only using regex. I've tried with `/^[0-9]/` but only the first digit gets affected. How to allow only the natural numbers between 1 and 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$quantity` comes from external input, such as `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST`, or `$_COOKIE` it's always going to be parsed as a string. You can use [`filter_input`](http://php.net/filter-input) to ensure your inputs are converted to the appropriate type.

For example, let's say you get this value from `$_POST["quantity"]` and you want to insure it's always a valid integer value between `1` and `10`.

```
if ($quantity = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "quantity", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, ["options" => ["min_range" => 1, "max_range" => 10]])) {
    // It's a valid value from 1 to 10
} else {
    // It's not a valid value we expect :(
}
```

Here are some test cases to demonstrate that it does what you want...

```
$values = [1, 0, 10, 11, '1', '0', '10', '11', '001', ',1'];

$opts = ["options" => ["min_range" => 1, "max_range" => 10]];

foreach($values as $value) {
    if ($quantity = filter_var($value,FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $opts)) {
        echo "\$quantity = $quantity which is VALID!\n";
    } else {
        echo "\$quantity = $value which is NOT valid :(\n";
    }
}
```

This should give you...

```
$quantity = 1 which is VALID!
$quantity = 0 which is NOT valid :(
$quantity = 10 which is VALID!
$quantity = 11 which is NOT valid :(
$quantity = 1 which is VALID!
$quantity = 0 which is NOT valid :(
$quantity = 10 which is VALID!
$quantity = 11 which is NOT valid :(
$quantity = 001 which is NOT valid :(
$quantity = ,1 which is NOT valid :(
```

Comment: No. Look at the test cases.

Comment: Nice to know about this function. I get this value from $_GET. I tried your code using INPUT_GET but don't worked, the code is accepting values such 01, ,1...

Comment: It would help to explain what it did that qualifies as "_don't worked_". Otherwise, I have no idea what you're doing wrong. The code works. The question is what did you do different or what was the result of the code working that was different than what you expected.

Comment: Well, I use `$quantity = isset($_GET['quantity']) ? $_GET['quantity'] : "";` to get the var. Maybe the problem is here?

Comment: Nice use of filter_var @Sherif

Comment: Right, if you're using `filter_input` you don't need to touch `$_GET`. You would just say `$quantity = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'quantity', ...)` as already clearly demonstrated in my answer. Where you do ever see me using the variables `$_POST` or `$_GET`?

Comment: Ok, but from where the $quantity variable comes from if I did not define it with get?

Comment: It still comes from `$_GET`. `filter_input` is just the one taking it from `$_GET` instead of you doing it directly.

Comment: Worked now using my original code. I just replaced `$quantity = isset($_GET['quantity']) ? $_GET['quantity'] : "";` with `$quantity = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "quantity", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)`

Comment: Sure, don't forget that you can specify the `options` argument to include the `min_range` and `max_range` as demonstrated in the answer to also include our range requirements. There's absolutely no need to write redundant code if you can help it ;)

Comment: As I said, I'm using the same code: `if($quantity <= 0 || $quantity > 10)
{
    redirect('page.php?msg=error');
    exit();
}` Defining the options in filter_input can't let me do the validation as I want.

Comment: Sure it can. That's ___exactly___ what the code in my answer does. It validates that the input is a natural number ___and___ is in the expected range. It just does it a single line of code instead of two. There are fewer opportunities to make a mistake when you're writing fewer lines of code ;)

Answer (score 0):

why not attack it the other way?

```
 if (is_int($quantity) === FALSE)
  // Your redirect code
 if (strlen(strval(intval($quantity))) != strlen($quantity))
   // Your redirect code
```

Add that before your first `if` above and that solves your 'other issues'

Comment: With this I need to use two ifs?

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot about the "10"

```
preg_match("/^([0-9]|10)(\D*)/", "10");
```

Answer (score 0):

`0001` is `1` so there is that. If you wanted to keep it with out loops and regular expressions you can do the following. This does allow `01`, `001` and `1`, though.

```
<?php

$a_number = '0001' + 0; // type juggle (int or float)

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($a_number); // is int(1)
echo '</pre>';

  if (is_numeric($a_number) 
    && is_int($a_number) // don't allow floats
    && $a_number > 0 
    && $a_number <= 10)
  {
      var_dump($a_number);
      echo 'ok!';
      exit;
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'page.php?msg=error';
    exit;
  }
```